# How to invoke a variable set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command, escaping

How can I modify the following code in such a way that the variable containing the directory path and msbuild executable gets invoked properly?

The problem is the spacing within `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.

How can I include spacing in the aforementioned msbuild command?

```
@echo ON SETLOCAL

set specificVersionedMsBuild=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

%specificVersionedMsBuild% /t:Clean
```

Comment: `SETLOCAL` should be on a different line, or separated with an ampersand. `set specificVersionedMsBuild=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\MSBuild.exe` should be `set "specificVersionedMsBuild=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\MSBuild.exe"`, and `%specificVersionedMsBuild%` should be `"%specificVersionedMsBuild%"`.

Comment: And if we were to pick everything apart @KJ, `@echo ON`, is also normally redundant, however as neither that, or using `SETLOCAL` were never going to be a potential cause for the reported issue, I didn't see the need, on this occasion, to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

@Compo Thank you for you comment, but here is what I ended up implementing:

```
set specificVersionedMsBuild=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
 
"%specificVersionedMsBuild%" /t:Clean
```